# Powershell script executed from SQL Server - stops working if put to background job

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I execute a PowerShell script to create folders and inbox-rules in Office365.

The script works fine when called from SQL Server.

But if I put the code in function and calls with `Start-Job` then it stops working from SQL Server - but it will work if executed from local machine(?)

I really want code to run in background because it takes 2-3 minutes to complete.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

This is code that works from SQL Server:

```
param( 
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderName 
    )

-- CODE HERE --

-- End of file
```

This is my code with ScriptBlock (does not work from sql, but works from local machine/server):

```
param( 
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderName 
    )

$func = {function createFolderAndRule {
    param([string]$FolderName)
    #-- CODE HERE --

}
}


Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($tm) createFolderAndRule $tm } -InitializationScript $func -ArgumentList($FolderName)
# End of file
```

Comment: How are you calling the PowerShell script from SQL Server? Is there an error message when the script doesn't work?

Comment: set _at_cmd = 'powershell "D:\PS\NewProject.ps1"'+' ' + _at_folder 
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell _at_cmd

The sql output:
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------  
1      Job1            BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost 

Maybe it is permission error?

Comment: Using *Sql Server* to create *Office365 rules* is a bit... personal approach. Maybe you could do the same with, say, Task Scheduler instead?

Comment: It is personal yes :)
Every new project created in the database should trigger a new inbox-rule in Exchange. 
Any other approach to solve this is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using PowerShell jobs to process your script asynchronously, a more conventional approach might be to add the O365 folder name you want to create to a table in the database, which is in turn used to drive a SQL Server Agent job which executes the PowerShell script. The SQL Server Agent job could poll the table on a schedule for new folders to create. You might still need to trigger the script from `xp_cmdshell`, because SQL Server Agent job steps can be fiddly to parameterise.

If you prefer to stick with the method you're using, probably the only way to debug this is to retrieve the output of the PowerShell job by modifying your script so that it does something like:

```
param( 
     [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FolderName 
    )

$func = {function createFolderAndRule {
    param([string]$FolderName)
    #-- CODE HERE --
}
}


Start-Job -ScriptBlock {param($tm) createFolderAndRule $tm } -InitializationScript $func -ArgumentList($FolderName)

Start-Sleep -s 300 #sleep 5 mins

Receive-Job -Id 1 #retrieve the output of the PowerShell job

Remove-Job -Id 1
```

Comment: Thank you! 

One step closer it seems.
The script actually works when using the
`Start-Sleep -s 300 #sleep 5 mins` 
But it does not work if the sleep period is i.e. 2 seconds ...

Comment: @methosmen - the implication is that the running PS job is terminated when the parent `xp_cmdshell` command finishes, regardless of the state of the job; adding the 5 minute wait gives the job time to complete. On that basis, you will not be able to run the command asynchronously - you will have to run it synchronously and either accept that it takes several minutes, or use another process to trigger the script by processing a queue (as I suggested with SQL Server agent).